# CS0122: is inaccessible due to its protection level

Tags: c#, build-error

Есть класс и код, взаимодействующий с ним. При сборке возникают ошибки непонятно по какой причине - все модификаторы установлены как public.

Класс

```
namespace lib60870.CS101 {
 public class VariableLengthDataArray : InformationObject {
  public override int GetEncodedSize() => 2 + this.StructLength;

  public override TypeID Type => TypeID.M_IT_ND_1;

  public override bool SupportsSequence => true;
  public byte StructLength { get; }
  public byte StructType { get; }
  public byte[] DataArray { get; }


  public VariableLengthDataArray(int ioa, byte structLength, byte structType, byte[] dataArray) : base(ioa) {
   this.StructLength = structLength;
   this.StructType = structType;
   this.DataArray = dataArray;
  }
 }
}
```

Ошибка

```
CS0122: 'VariableLengthDataArray' is inaccessible due to its protection level
```

Строки, вызывающие ошибку  - 3,5,7

```
1. Console.WriteLine(
2.                   "\tStructLength: " +
3.                   ((VariableLengthDataArray)asdu.GetElement(i)).StructLength +
4.                   "\n\tStructType: " +
5.                   ((VariableLengthDataArray)asdu.GetElement(i)).StructType +
6.                   "\n\tDataArray: " +
7.                   ((VariableLengthDataArray)asdu.GetElement(i)).DataArray);
```

При том если добавить класс в `Project.cs`, всё работает.

Comment: у вас может где то есть второй класс с таким же названием? Попробуйте указать пространство имен `((lib60870.CS101.VariableLengthDataArray)asdu.GetElement(i)).StructLength`

Comment: такая ошибка возникает когда  элементы класса имеют параметр `private `или его конструктор `private` по умолчанию всегда `private` если не написано `public`

Comment: @tym32167 Путь к классу отображается корректно. А при перемещении класса в файл с Main'ом всё работает.

Comment: @OXYGEN Класс и всё, что есть внутри, имеет модификатор public

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Необходимо пересобрать проект, содержащий указанные классы